# Adddional compiler flags for f2py

Tags: python, f2py

I would like to use the flag `-ftree-vectorize` ([compiler manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/tree-ssa/vectorization.html)) as addional argument for the gnu fortran compiler used by f2py. According to the [f2py manual](https://sysbio.ioc.ee/projects/f2py2e/usersguide/#command-f2py) it should be possible by using the argument `--f90flags=<string>`
However, i get the error `error: unknown file type '' (from --f90flag=-ftree-vectorize)`. I am using f2py from the anaconda distribution on Windows 7 64bit.

The command i am using:

`f2py.py -c -m myfun  myfun.f90 --fcompiler=gnu95  --f90flag=ftree-vectorize`

Additionally, I tried `--f90flag=msse2` but the error stays the same.

Any suggestions how to pass additional compiler flags to f2py ?

Answer (score 3):

I override default fortran flags by doing

```
f2py -c --verbose --opt='-O3' modules.pyf modules.f90
```

Probably you can try

```
f2py -c --verbose --opt='-ftree-vectorize' modules.pyf modules.f90
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [official website of numpy-f2py](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/f2py/usage.html), the characters that follow `--f90flags=` are actually a `<string>`, we simply need to incorporate more flags inside the single quotation marks. For example

```
--f90flags='-g -fimplicit-none -fopenmp -O3'
```