# Compile legacy fortran77 code as python module using f2py

Tags: python, fortran, fortran77, f2py

I am able to successfully compile FORTRAN77 code, but only when specifying `-std=legacy` in

```
gfortran -o -std=legacy -o model.exe model.FOR
```

Without `-std=legacy`, I get some fatal errors. I wish to similarly specify a legacy compiler when attempting to build a python module. Presently the following call generates the same fatal errors as those when omitting `-std=legacy` using gfortran.

```
f2py -c -m pymodel model.FOR --fcompiler=gnu95
```

Any suggestions on how to ensure f2py uses a legacy compiler compatible with antiquated FORTRAN77 code?

Comment: Are you actually just asking how to pass that flag to the compiler? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28380548/adddional-compiler-flags-for-f2py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are you actually just asking how to pass that flag to the compiler? stackoverflow.com/questions/28380548/…

Vladimir F provided a good reference. f2py compiles when passing the argument of interest into `--opt="__"`:

```
f2py -c --opt='-std=legacy' -m pymodel model.FOR --fcompiler=gnu95
```